# The definition of struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I am confused about the following definition of the struct.

```
struct Matrix{
    int a, b;
    Matrix(int a =0, b = 0): a(a), b(b){} 
} m[26];
```

What does the statement "Matrix(int a =0, b = 0): a(a), b(b){} " mean and why we need it? Does "m[26]" means we define an array of Matrix?

Comment: This question is mistagged: It has `c` but _not_ `c++`. The construct is a C++ construct. It is a "constructor". Edited the tags.

Comment: Yes, `m[26]` means it's declaring an array of the structures.

Comment: Perhaps a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will be more useful here.

Answer (score 0):

The `m[26]` says to create an array of 26 of the `struct Matrix type.`  That is fine in `C`.

However, the `Matrix(int a=0, b==0): a(a), b(b) {}` is specifying a constructor which assigns `a` and `b` parameters to `a` and `b` member variables in the `struct Matrix` is `c++`.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
Matrix(int a = 0, b = 0) :
    a(a), b(b)
{
}
```

is a constructor with two parameters, `a` and `b`. They have default values, each being 0.

It initializes its member variables `a` and `b` with the provided arguments.

You can use it for example like this:

```cpp
Matrix m1;         // initializes a and b with 0 each
Matrix m2(23);     //  initializes a and b with 23 and 0, respectively
Matrix m3(23, 42); //  initializes a and b with 23 and 42, respectively
```